# How to remove "Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.02 with Leptonica" message

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

When I use pytesser (the image processing lib with tesseract-ocr for python) and run:

```
image= Image.open(ImagePath)
text = image_to_string(image)
print text
```

as a result I get the `text`, as well as this line from tesseract:

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.02 with Leptonica
```

I think this line runs when the `image_to_string` function is run.

This really clogs up the output printed in the console. And is really annoying. Does anyone know how to get rid of it? Maybe a line in python or something?

Comment: See the [comments on the README](https://code.google.com/p/pytesser/wiki/README#commentlist) on the pytesser page - there's two workarounds posted by people addressing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do is open `pytesser.py` in the main `pytesser` folder and change this function:

```
def call_tesseract(input_filename, output_filename):
    """Calls external tesseract.exe on input file (restrictions on types),
    outputting output_filename+'txt'"""
    args = [tesseract_exe_name, input_filename, output_filename]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(args)
    retcode = proc.wait()
    if retcode!=0:
        errors.check_for_errors()
```

to

```
def call_tesseract(input_filename, output_filename):
    """Calls external tesseract.exe on input file (restrictions on types),
    outputting output_filename+'txt'"""
    devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')
    args = [tesseract_exe_name, input_filename, output_filename]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stderr=devnull)
    retcode = proc.wait()
    if retcode!=0:
        errors.check_for_errors()
```

and also add `import os` to the top of the file.

Comment: Checked the file, there is no function named call__tesseract. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Frist create a config file

```
cat <<CNF >>/usr/share/tessdata/tessconfigs/nobanner
debug_file /dev/null
CNF
```

*Note that your tessconfigs could be somewhere else, likes /usr/local/share/tessdata/tessconfigs.*

Then use 'nobanner' on the command line

```
tesseract infile.png outprefix -l eng nobanner
```

Answer (score 1):

only the code below got success:

```
tesseract infile.png outprefix 1>/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to [redirect it to a log file](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_make_the_error_messages_go_to_tesseract.log_instead_of) by setting the `debug_file` parameter.

Comment: How exactly do I do that...?

Comment: Call `api.SetVariable("debug_file", "tesseract.log")` after `api.Init`.